# Big O approximation for limit

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, asymptotics

This question is more about the notation. The function $\zeta(s)$ is irrelevant.

> Since
>   $$ \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \Big\{ \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} \Big\} = \gamma. $$
>   we have 
>   $$ \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma+ O(|s-1|)$$
>   Page 16, Titchmarsh.

I don't understand why we have the Big  O equality.

Suppose $\lim_s h(s) = 0 $ does that mean $h(s) = O(s)$? My definition for $O(s)$: there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all $|s| <\delta$, 
$$ |h(s)| \le M |s|.$$ 
But clearly this does not hold? Take $h(s) = \sqrt{s}$. So what exactly is meant by the author?

Comment: No, $h(s) \to 0$ doesn't imply $h(s) \in O(s)$ by itself. But $s \mapsto \zeta(s) - \dfrac{1}{s-1}$ is a holomorphic function, and thus is differentiable. The Taylor expansion then gives $\zeta(s) = \dfrac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + \gamma_1(s-1) + \gamma_2(s-1)^2 + \dotsc$.

Comment: around $s=1$ : $\eta(s) =(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ is analytic means $F(s) = (s-1) \zeta(s)$ is analytic which means $\zeta(s)- \frac{F(1)}{s-1}$ is analytic. You get $F(1)= 1$ for example from $\eta(1) = -\log(1-1/2) = \log 2$, or more direct from $\zeta(s) = s \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx =  \frac{s}{s-1}+s \int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor-x) x^{-s-1}dx$.  Finally $\gamma$ is by definition $F'(1)$, and with a little work you'll show it is also $-\Gamma'(1)$

Answer (score 0):

Definition: A function $g(s)$ is $O(|s-1|)$ as $s\to 1$ iff there exists $r>0$ and $K>0$ such that $$\forall s\in (-r+1,r+1) \backslash \{1\}\; (|g(s)|\leq K|s-1|).$$

Example: $\sqrt {|s-1|}$ is NOT $O(|s-1|)$ as $s\to 1.$